# Salesforce certification expiration

Tags: certification, platform-developer-2

I have completed my Platform developer 1 exams (Last year)and now I need to complete my **maintenance exam by paying 100$** and my question is

what If I take Platform developer 2 exams do I **still need to pay 100$ for PD1 maintenance exam** or will it be Free

**what If I didn't take PD1 maintenance will my PD2 certification also expires or PD1 alone?**

what Will happen?

Comment: If it follows the same mechanics as the ADM201, not refreshing PD1 would make PD2 expire

Comment: okay got it but should I need to pay for PD1 maintenance or will it be free ??

Comment: Do you pay 100$ yearly for the ADM201 refresh ? Yes. Is ADM201 required for other certifications for which you have to pay ? By analogy, it would be a yes for PD1 and PD2.

Answer (score 1):

1.You don't have to pay anything for maintenance of certification(unless it is **expired**).

2.You can take Platform Developer II exam if your Platform Developer I certification is **not expired** and you have completed all the **prerequisites**.

3.If your Platform Developer I certification expires and you also hold the Platform Developer II certification, the Platform Developer II certification will be placed in a **suspended state**. You will then have one release cycle from the expiration date to re-certify as a Platform Developer I, at which point the suspended Platform Developer II certification will be **reinstated**.

**For more information about certification expiration read this:** https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Information-about-Certification-Expiration